# Calling a method/function anytime a val/var is declared (without explicit method/function called)

Tags: scala

Editing due to a combination of an overly complex example and not cleary stating my intentions.

I have a `class` that designers will extend from and build. To keep code clean I would like to be able to do a combination of actions when specific classes are instantiated.

I know that I can use a Companion Object with custom `apply()` to do most of this, and would work with the exception that I sort of need to know the class that is instantiating the specific class (and I'm trying to avoid passing `this` as a parameter).

```scala
class Apple{}
class Orange{}
class MyBase{
  val allApples  = ListBuffer[Apple]()
  val allOranges = ListBuffer[Orange]()
}

//User defined classes extending MyBase

class SomeNewClass extends MyBase{
  val apple1 = new Apple   //we would want to add apple1 to the allApples List
  val apple2 = new Apple
  val orange1 = new Orange

}

class AnotherClass extends MyBase{
  val someClass = new SomeNewClass

  val apple1 = new Apple
}
```

So you can see that I want to be able to add the Apple instances to the allApples ListBuffer and same for the oranges. I'd like to be able to do this without *requiring* an `addApple` type of method. The problem is, I have no reference to `SomeNewClass` or `AnotherClass` (or whatever else the designer would make). I *could* have an implicit like the following:

```scala
class Apple()(implicit myBaseCaller : MyBase){
  myBaseCaller.addApple(this)
}
class MyBase{
  implicit val myself : MyBase = this
  //excluded for clarity
}
```

Instantiating a new Apple or Orange outside of a class that extends MyBase would be a violation of the DSL in this particular case.

So I don't disagree that the best solution would be an explicit method to addApples, however I'm trying to see if there is a solution that is easier on the coding.

There may not be a decent way to do it, which would be ok. In this case I don't mind a little extra overhead in the base classes to make the extended classes easier to write.

**Removed Original Question as too complicated**

Comment: Sounds like an horrible design, for many reasons. Including the implicit behaviour, and the mutable global state.

Comment: Assuming object "tracking" is your main concern - have you considered creating a factory function that would a) instantiate the object b) add it to a list / data structure of your choice c) return both or store it somewhere in a less functional variant? From what you've described, reflection doesn't seem like the right way to go, although, I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instantiating a new Apple or Orange outside of a class that extends MyBase would be a violation of the DSL in this particular case.

It's not clear from the context whether that would be desirable or not.

In any case, have you considered what might be accomplished with a private constructor and a public auxiliary constructor?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class MyBase{
  class Apple private (lb :ListBuffer[Apple]) {
    lb += this
    def this() = this(allApples)
  }
  class Orange private (lb :ListBuffer[Orange]) {
    lb += this
    def this() = this(allOranges)
  }
  val allApples  = ListBuffer[Apple]()
  val allOranges = ListBuffer[Orange]()
}

class SomeNewClass extends MyBase{
  val apple1 = new Apple
  val apple2 = new Apple
  val orange1 = new Orange
}

class AnotherClass extends MyBase{
  val someClass = new SomeNewClass
  val apple1 = new Apple
}

val snc = new SomeNewClass
val ac = new AnotherClass
snc.allApples.size   //res0: Int = 2
snc.allOranges.size  //res1: Int = 1
ac.allApples.size    //res2: Int = 1
ac.allOranges.size   //res3: Int = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution I was looking for. The DSL violation would obviously be a requirement in this case, but considering the usecases we have I believe this is actually ok.